# TemplateSyntaxError and SyntaxErrors with template inclusion tags

Tags: python, django, include, django-views

This is my previous post. [Template includes and django views/urls. How (do/should) they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130676/template-includes-and-django-views-urls-how-do-should-they-work/10130996#10130996) .

Again, the mini box works fine. I've taken the advice given and trying to work with it.

So I have a `profile(request, profile_type, username)` view. I'm trying to grab the 'profile_intros'context from that and place it into the included mini_profile.html template.

I've tried making an inclusion tag(as I will be needing it elsewhere throughout the site):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('includes/profile_info.html', takes_context=True)(profile_info)
     def profile_info(context):
         profile_intros = FundRecommendation.objects.filter(investor=profile).count()
         return{
             'profile_intros' : context['profile_intros'],
         }
```

and throwing `{% profile_info %}` into the included mini_profile.html template. I've followed the django doc example and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm getting :

```
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Invalid block tag: 'profile_info'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `{% load ... %}` to load the template tag library.

Comment: I tried that and also added `django.contrib.profile_info`, to my installed apps. I cannot start up my server or syndb due to `Error: No module named profile_info` in my console. :\

Comment: Why do you believe that "django.contrib.profile_info" is the correct value to add?

Comment: Examples. I'm a n00b(at best) and I'm just trying to play around with it. All of my apps are already there, I'm not really sure what else to add to be honest.

Comment: Take a few minutes to read the [modules section of the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html), then start the Django shell and try a few imports until you find the one you need.